# alamofire how to use taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection

Tags: http, redirect, alamofire

i use  alamofire to handle http request but receive nil

and the url has a server http redirect , how can i use taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection  to allow perform http redirection .

then i can receive the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that is currently possible. Here's a detailed [issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/314) on the Github project site that walks through the problem. There are also two open pull requests, [PR1](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/350) and [PR2](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/317), that attempt to address this problem if you wish to work off a fork temporarily.

Comment: thank for you suggestion. i decide to use NSURLSession finally

Comment: Okay cool. If you feel my answer helped, you should upvote and mark as the answer.